# Installed NuGet package not in namespace?

Tags: c#, nuget

I installed flawless this package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ini-parser/
https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser

It shows up in my project dependencies and i am using the directive suggested
by the author:

```
using IniParser;
using IniParser.Model;
```

But the "code" is not seen in my Form1.cs where i put the directive ?

Error CS0246.

I am a beginner so you know.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces

Comment: Please note that the [guidance on tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) suggests avoiding putting tags in your question title except where it flows naturally as part of the question title. With regards to your question: can you give more context on how you're using ini-parser? And did you confirm that NuGet really did install it? It can be a little finicky at times.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to understand how to apply `[using][1]` and differences between `Directive` and `static Directive` and normally diagnostic with fully qualified type name to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the nuget and put the using directives in and could instantly use it

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
   using System.Windows.Forms;

   using IniParser;

   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
         var data = parser.ReadFile("Configuration.ini");

         var useFullScreenStr = data["UI"]["fullscreen"];

         var useFullScreen = bool.Parse(useFullScreenStr);

         data["UI"]["fullscreen"] = "true";
         parser.WriteFile("Configuration.ini", data);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was an easy solution. I had to refresh the library or package dependencies and it instantly found it. Thank you for the answers.